# AmbigousActionException With Two Completely Different Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am receiving an `AmbiguousActionException` between two actions which are part of two separate controllers, and I'm curious as to why. (The solution is simple - change the route on `MyAdminController`, so I'm not so much looking for that.)

Here is the one action:

```
[Route("Admin/Company")]
public class MyAdminController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet("{id}/Details")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
  {
    // Do stuff.
  }
}
```

And the second:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ConfigurationController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet("Scripts/{id}")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Scripts(long id)
  {
    // Do stuff.
  }
}
```

ASP.NET Core 1, MVC 6 is the technology stack. I'm sure I'm missing some basic, key thing with routing, but I'm not understanding what.